# Are gas prices determined by how large an array is when adding to it?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas

I am looking at a contract where the array of digital items will get larger and larger as time goes by. Im wondering what the cost implications are over the long run as the Dapp matures, especially when it comes to adding to the array.

Please take the following basic example which assumes gas prices etc stay the same.

**Example**

Lets say at the start when I add my initial item after creating the contract it costs $1 to run the contract.

Now lets say a period of x days/months goes by and the array is now up to lets say 100000 items. Now when i run the contract to add a new item will the cost still be $1 or will it now increase because the size of the array has increased?

Also when fetching/reading the array from my web app is there a cost associated with this? I have read somewhere that reads from the blockchain don't cost anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, transaction **cost** is different than gas **price**.

Gas price is independent of the code itself. The gas price can be anything you like, with the caveat that the lower the price you set for the gas, the higher the time it will take for your transaction to be mined.

Now, the gas used by the transaction, which if you multiply it by the gas price it will give you how much the transaction costed, is calculated by the processing the function called had to do.

The more lines of code or the more complex the calculations you do, state variables you access and/or store/modify, the higher the gas that will be used.

As far as I know, adding an item to an array/mapping will cost the same gas regardless of how many items that array/mapping already is storing.

Accessing just one element by index should cost the same regardless of the amount of items it is holding.

Reading from the blockchain still consumes gas but you don't have to pay for it, so reading is free. BUT, you are still bound by gas limits. Even if you don't have to pay for the gas, gas is consumed and if the function does some heavy computing it will run out of gas and fail.

Comment: Thanks for that it has really cleared things up for me. I will try and keep the code as segmented as possible to reduce overheads.

Comment: Suppose if we have thousads of data in the array and i want to retrieve the whole array data is it possible that before running the function i get to know the gas consume by function so i can restrict the fetching of data with the maximum number of rows ?