# Gas cost of adding an item to a class-level (storage) array

Tags: gas, evm, storage, arrays, gas-estimate

I would like to make sure that the gas cost of adding an item to a (storage) array is constant, i.e., not dependent on the length of the array.

To my understanding, the relevant EVM operation is `SSTORE`, which according to [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6mRqkBz3iWcOlRem_mO09GtSKEKrAsfO7Frgx18pNU/edit#gid=0) (taken from the yellow paper), has indeed a "more or less constant" gas cost.

In addition to that, I also found [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35100/are-gas-prices-determined-by-how-large-an-array-is-when-adding-to-it/35101#35101) to support it, stating:

> As far as I know, adding an item to an array/mapping will cost the same gas regardless of how many items that array/mapping already is storing.

Due to the "as far as I know" part, I also executed some testing against a "real" EVM (using Truffle and Ganache).

**Here is my on-chain code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract MyContract {
    uint256[] public array;
    function justPush(uint256 value) external {
        array.push(value);
    }
}
```

**Here is my off-chain code:**

```
contract("test", function() {
    it("pushing an 'all-0s' value", async function() {await justPush(1);});
    it("pushing an 'all-1s' value", async function() {await justPush(2);});

    async function justPush(n) {
        let myContract = await artifacts.require("MyContract.sol").new();
        let value = web3.toBigNumber(n).pow(256).minus(1);
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            let gas = await myContract.justPush.estimateGas(value);
            await myContract.justPush(value);
            console.log(gas);
        }
    }
});
```

**And here is my observation:**

- Pushing an "all-0s" value costs 46951 units for the first insertion and 31951 units for every other insertion
- Pushing an "all-1s" value costs 63999 units for the first insertion and 48999 units for every other insertion

As I started off with - I would like to make sure that the gas cost of this operation is indeed constant, even though the operation of adding an element to an array which not implemented as a linked list has a theoretical time complexity of O(n).

Also, am I right in guessing that the difference between the first insertion and every other insertion is due to the fact that the length of the array is changed from 0 to 1?

Thank you!